# Why reducing num_workers and increasing batch size makes the CNN training faster with better ACC values?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, cpu

I have a i5-7500, quad core CPU and a 2GB GPU. The higher the number of workers (0, to 4) the slower the training speed and the ACC values are also lowering. I noticed a difference in time in each epoch, from 45 secs with 4 num_workers and batch_size of 1225, to 15 secs with 0 num_workers and same batch size.

Comment: I don't think it causes better accuracy (maybe it was luck, the model had a better random initialization or something in that sense). But, about the number of works, I say it depends on the storage that you are fetching the data from (as well as many other things). For example, it is a bad idea to have multiple works if the data is on HDD storage since the head of the storage should jump more and that takes time.